# SpriteKit crashing on update [SKScene _update:] how can i fix this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, sprite-kit

After release ios 8.3 i began getting a crash reports from users, i can't figure out on which version of ios it is occurred, only i have is this crash report...
I think this is Sprite Kit bug and i also think that this occurs when app is going to background.

Stack Trace

---

1     SpriteKit                             0x3104c3f3 _ZN9SKCSprite6updateEd + 351

2     SpriteKit                             0x3104c3f3 _ZN9SKCSprite6updateEd + 348

3     SpriteKit                             0x3104c3f3 _ZN9SKCSprite6updateEd + 348

4     SpriteKit                             0x3104c3f3 _ZN9SKCSprite6updateEd + 348

5     SpriteKit                             0x31014caf -[SKScene _update:] + 172

6     SpriteKit                             0x31029599 -[SKView(Private) _update:] + 322

7     SpriteKit                             0x31026c2b -[SKView renderCallback:] + 816

8     SpriteKit                             0x31024663 __29-[SKView setUpRenderCallback]_block_invoke + 128

9     SpriteKit                             0x31046ddb -[SKDisplayLink _callbackForNextFrame:] + 252

10   QuartzCore                             0x30e069cf _ZN2CA7Display15DisplayLinkItem8dispatchEv + 96

11   QuartzCore                             0x30e06779 _ZN2CA7Display11DisplayLink14dispatch_itemsEyyy + 342

12   IOMobileFramebuffer                    0x33a3376d IOMobileFramebufferVsyncNotifyFunc + 102

13   IOKit                                  0x2f69ea75 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 246

14   CoreFoundation                         0x2e97ce21 __CFMachPortPerform + 134

15   CoreFoundation                         0x2e9879df **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 32

16   CoreFoundation                         0x2e98797b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 344

17   CoreFoundation                         0x2e98614f __CFRunLoopRun + 1396

18   CoreFoundation                         0x2e8f0c27 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520

19   CoreFoundation                         0x2e8f0a0b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104

20   GraphicsServices                       0x33617283 GSEventRunModal + 136

21   UIKit                                  0x31194049 UIApplicationMain + 1134

22   Dotox                                  0x000f5047 main (main.m:16)

23   libdyld.dylib                          0x39305ab7 start + 0

Comment: Are you using anything that is iOS release specific?